# how to compare two values and then show relevant data in option tag

Tags: php

here is my code and I want to embed this code

```
<?php echo ($res['h_id']==$row['h_id'])?'selected':'' ?>
```

into this one code to select the specific value from option tag when page loads

```
<?php
         $con = new Hostel();
         $res=$con->getHostelName();
         while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<option value=\"{$row['h_id']}\">";
           echo $row['h_name'];
           echo "</option>";
         }
?>
```

Comment: what a logic. `$res` is a resultset, `$row` is current row. Why should they `$res['h_id']==$row['h_id']` be equal?

Comment: Not Getting How `$res['h_id']==$row['h_id']` ?

Comment: $res['h_id'] is different array i did't mean to use this one $res $res=$con->getHostelName();.... achtually i am not using correct naming conventions

Comment: the below answer did work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $con = new Hostel();
    $res=$con->getHostelName();
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option ".($res['h_id']==$row['h_id'] ? 'selected' : '' )." value=\"{$row['h_id']}\">";
        echo $row['h_name'];
    echo "</option>";
    }
?>
```